# How can I find unused artifacts in BizTalk 2013?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I've inherited a BizTalk installation where control over the source code has not been great.  This has left us with a BizTalk application where we can't guarantee that we have the correct source.  What we propose is to rebuild the application from the source that we have and then re-test it.
Local knowledge of the application is low so I'd like to reduce the amount of re-testing required.  I'll then get it all properly under source control and documented.

From that what I'd like to do is determine what orchestrations, pipelines maps etc. are actually in use in the live environment.

Can anyone recommend tools, queries or approaches that will help identify which parts of a BizTalk application are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, there no real way to automatically know what's in use or not.  To BizTalk, anything deployed is in-use or may be used.

To fine out what has run recently (over any time period) you can query the DTA database.

Join **dta_ServiceInstances** and **dta_Services** using uidServiceId to see what Orchestrations and Pipelines have been run.

Make sure [Global Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-turn-off-global-tracking) has not been disabled, it should never be disabled.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was after.  I've thrown together a query and passed it on to our server team to run against the live environment, hopefully it'll show what we can rid of..

Answer (score 0):

Our support and maintenance Tool [Nodinite](https://www.nodinite.com/) has the features you are asking for (listing a few of those you asked for that may help):

- **Reports** with usage of BizTalk artifacts (for example, for selected [host instance](https://documentation.nodinite.com/Documentation/LoggingAndMonitoring%2FMicrosoft%20BizTalk%20Server%20-%20Monitoring?doc=/Features/Host%20Instances/Actions/Details) shows how it's being used, ports, orchestrations, port/handler e.g adapters)
- **Assembly comparer** (makes sure you have the same set of binaries on all BizTak servers)
- Automatic discovery of ports and then with tracking enabled you will very soon find out if there is **traffic at all** on those [ports/endpoints](https://documentation.nodinite.com/Documentation/RepositoryModel?doc=/Endpoints/Overview)
- The [Repository](https://documentation.nodinite.com/Documentation/RepositoryModel) is a great way of documenting your solutions as you explore and make findings of your existing environment, also used in both logging and monitoring (and alerts). You can use Qlik/PowerBI/Excel with the [WebAPI](https://documentation.nodinite.com/Documentation/CoreServices?doc=/Web%20API/Overview) for further custom reporting
- [Additional Monitoring](https://documentation.nodinite.com/Documentation/Monitoring) for BizTalk can be found [here](https://documentation.nodinite.com/Documentation/LoggingAndMonitoring/Microsoft%20BizTalk%20Server%20-%20Monitoring)